# Big text appears for few second on page refresh in IE, How to solve?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, sifr, sifr3

Text always appears in big size for a few seconds when one refreshes the page on IE only, which doesn't look very good. pleas look at IE 7 and try to refresh (I've e.g. been pressing ctrl + F5) to see what i'm facing.

I'm also using sIFR on this site

I check a js error of page and this is the problematic area.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var arr = new Array(3)
arr[0] = "Jani"
arr[1] = "Tove"
arr[2] = "Hege"var arr2 = new Array(3)
arr2[0] = "John"
arr2[1] = "Andy"
arr2[2] = "Wendy"document.write(arr.concat(arr2))</script>
```

Comment: Do you realize that one of the sites you have on your resume has been hacked and defaced thanks to sloppy coding? http://lampmasters.com

Comment: Also, none of the resources in the site is being cached. Is this by design? This is partially making things worse too, because your site takes a long time to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Firebug it looks like you're missing some semicolons in the javascript.

**Edit: I think it should be like this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = new Array(3);
    arr[0] = "Jani"
    arr[1] = "Tove"
    arr[2] = "Hege";
    var arr2 = new Array(3);
    arr2[0] = "John";
    arr2[1] = "Andy";
    arr2[2] = "Wendy";
    document.write(arr.concat(arr2));
</script>
```

As for the flashing of your H1:

You are using banners.js to randomly place new banner content into #homeTitle, but your source already has the code there. I'm think it is flashing because IE is rendering the source before the JS.

It looks like the three different banners you have link to different content, but you are randomly only showing one at a time. The hidden content is lost to the user. I would suggest having your different banners fade between each other so the user has the opportunity to see the content.

Comment: no i used ur code it's not solving problem and it's showing all arr name on top in header